# Computing play number for baseball stats in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to analyze some baseball stats and I'm having some trouble achieving what seems like it should be a simple task. Take a look at the following result set:

```
GAME_PK  REC_SEQ  BatterId  PlayNumber  EventType
287576   6        462101    1           single
287576   14       519048    2           single
287576   25       435079    3           strikeout
287576   26       435079    4           stolen_base_home
287576   28       435079    5           stolen_base_2b
```

The PlayNumber column is being generated by me using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GAME_PK, REC_SEQ). The rest comes directly from an MLB stats database. REC_SEQ is the sequence number of the event within the game. EventType is essentially the result of an at-bat.

I would like PlayNumber to increment only when the BatterId changes. But it must respect the ordering of REC_SEQ. So I don't think I can use RANK or DENSE_RANK, but those seem to be very close to what I need.

I would like my result set to look like this:

```
GAME_PK  REC_SEQ  BatterId  PlayNumber  EventType
287576   6        462101    1           single
287576   14       519048    2           single
287576   25       435079    3           strikeout
287576   26       435079    3           stolen_base_home
287576   28       435079    3           stolen_base_2b
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: A batter can appear more than once during a game. He should be assigned a new PlayNumber for each appearance. Basically, each new at-bat requires a new PlayNumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:  It seems like the only way this can be accomplished is to figure out where each group begins and ends by determining which sequential records share a batterId.  This is done by joining the records with themselves offset by 1 rownum to determine where each group begins.  Once we have a collection of the starts of each group (`GroupSets`), we can determine to which group each individual record belongs to produce the correct numbering:

```
with GroupSets as (
select
    row_number() over (order by s1.rec_seq) as rownum,
    s1.game_pk, s1.rec_seq, s1.batterid, s2.batterid as nextbatterid,
    s1.eventtype
from (select *, row_number() over (order by rec_seq) as rownum from stats) s1
left join (select rec_seq, batterid,
           row_number() over (order by rec_seq) as rownum from stats) s2
    on s1.rownum = s2.rownum + 1
where s1.batterid != s2.batterid or s2.batterid is null
)
select
    game_pk,
    rec_seq,
    batterid,
    (select max(rownum) from GroupSets gs where gs.Rec_Seq <= s1.rec_seq) as PlayNumber,
    eventtype
from
    stats s1;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5e68/50

---

old code that doesn't handle interleaving:

Actually the `DENSE_RANK()` function should do it.  However, we need to rank over the values of the `MIN(REC_SEQ)` per BatterId group in order to use `REC_SEQ` to control the order.  Something like this should do it:

```
select
    s1.game_pk,
    s1.rec_seq,
    s1.batterID,
    dense_rank() over (order by s2.rec_seq) as PlayNumber,
    s1.EventType
from
    stats s1
join
    (select batterid, min(rec_seq) rec_seq
     from stats group by batterid) s2 on s1.batterid = s2.batterid
order by
    rec_seq
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0682e/4

Comment: Since I don't have your source data, I'm pretending the sample you posted is the source data.  You should be able to adapt the concept to your own data source.  I'm also assuming here that the `BatterId` values are not interleaved, i.e., all the same BatterId values appear together in the `REC_SEQ` ordering.  If that is not the case, then that scenario is not defined, i.e., should they all adopt the same PlayNumber value, or get assigned new values?

Comment: The BatterId values ARE interleaved. So the same Batter can appear later in the game and should be assigned a new PlayNumber at that point. I basically want to assign a number for each time a batter steps up to the plate.

Comment: This has become exponentially more difficult, but I think I have it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5e68/50 :)  Basically have to figure out where the groups start and end by comparing each record with the following record to see if it's the same batterid.  Then once we have identified the groups, determine which group each record belongs to by finding the corresponding `REC_SEQ` that identifies the end of that particular group.

Comment: Your solution worked (as did the solution by Gordon Linoff), but they both took absolutely forever to run on my data set, so I ended up using a stored procedure with a CURSOR loop instead and it runs in about 5 seconds. But I'm awarding you the answer because you answered first, and technically your answer was correct. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is hard, but possible in SQL Server.  I will note that Oracle's analytic functions make this much easier.

The idea is the following:

- Add a strict sequence number so you can get the previous play in each game
- Use this to add a flag to the first time a play is at bat in a given sequence
- Enumerate these within a game to get the play number
- Join this back to the stats with an appropriate group by to assign the right play number

I think the following code does the trick:

```
with s_enum as 
(
   select s.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by game_pk order by rec_seq) as Seq
   from stats
) s_cp as 
(
   select s.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by game_pk, FirstInSeq) as BattingSeq
   from 
   (
     select s.*,
        (case when prev.BatterId = curr.BatterId then 1 else 0 end) as FirstInSeq
     from s_enum curr 
     left outer join s_enum prev
        on curr.game_pk = prev.game_pk 
        and curr.Seq = prev.Seq + 1
   )
)
select s.game_pk, s.batterid, s.rec_seq, MAX(bs.req_sec) as PlayNumber       
from stats s 
join
(
   select s.*
   from s_cp s
   where FirstInSeq = 1
) bs
  on s.game_pk = bs.game_pk 
  and s.batterid = bs.batterid 
  and s.rec_seq >= bs.req_sec
group by s.game_pk, s.batterid, s.rec_seq
```

Comment: "Oracle's analytic functions make this much easier." SQL Server 2012 supports `lead`, `lag`, `first_value` and `last_value`. If you meant any of those functions it would be of interest to have a solution using that as well. It might be an option for the OP to switch to SQL Server 2012 if he is not already using that version.